# Web Deploy to Azure Stopped Working even with downloaded publish profile

Tags: azure, webdeploy

My Web Deploy Publish from Visual Studio 2017 to my Azure web app was being finicky yesterday, and today just stopped working completely.

Yesterday the error in Event Viewer was

```
Error Code:  6  Exception Message:  Could not connect to the remote computer ("MYDOMAIN.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.  Exception Stack Trace: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponseHelper(HttpWebRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
Could not connect to the remote computer ("MYDOMAIN.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponseHelper(HttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.PerformHeadRequestHelper(Boolean getVersionInfo, Version& maximumSupportedVersion, Version& minimumSupportedVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateDestinationObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
```

Today the error is :

```
Error Code:  103  Exception Message:  Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.  Exception Stack Trace: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventSerializer.Deserialize(Stream responseStream, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventSerializer.Deserialize(Stream responseStream, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, Nullable`1 syncPass, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
```

After looking at many inconclusive posts on the matter, (and since this error ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED is not listed on the official troubleshoot website they provide in the error), I did the following:
(1) Restart my computer
(2) Restart Visual Studio
(3) Open Visual Studio as Admin
(4) Redownload the Publish profile from Azure

None of this worked.

In the publish profile window, when I click "Validate" for my credentials, they pass. Only when I preview or run the publish does it error out.

What finally worked was

(5) Set Application setting to false in Azure WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM

I looked it up and am not sure what it did, and why I needed to do it, and why it worked fine before without this setting. It feels like a hack fix and I don't like it. Should I keep this application setting?

UPDATE:
Not sure if the SCM setting helped. I was able to publish once, and no can't again.

Comment: what if the issue is in Azure side, did you try re-creating the App Service?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia what does it mean to re-create the App Serivce?

Comment: There are many reasons for this problem, please make sure your deployment tools are fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, Close the firewall and the local proxy-based software.

Second, Make sure you have install the web deploy handler and all of the options has be installed.

[image]

(Add the option not be selected.)

Thrid, Make sure you dont have IP restrictions for Management Service.

Other possible reasons you can find in this Offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio